# Instance member cannot be used on type when adding UIImage Programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I'm new to Swift, and I'm still trying to get my head around many things. I made a class for a Meteorite:

```
class Meteorite {
        var width: Int,
            height: Int,
            x: Int,
            y : Int

        init(width: Int, height: Int, x: Int, y: Int) {
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

            let image = UIImage(named: "square")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.x, y: self.y, width: self.width, height: self.height)
            view.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
```

... And I'm trying to make the meteors appear through UIImage View elements. However, on the line: `view.addSubview(imageView)`

I keep getting thrown the error:

> Instance member 'view' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

I might be doing this wrong, but this class is defined within the ViewController class, which is a subclass of UIViewController. I can't find anything that makes much sense to my situation online. Help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Meteorite` may be nested within a `UIViewController` subclass, but you are still referencing a `view` property within the context of the `Meteorite` class. Essentially, you are sending a message to a variable that doesn't exist.

The thing to do here is to move any manipulation of the view hierarchy outside of the init for an element. This should be handled by the view controller, not the subview.

I would suggest configuring the `Meteorite` object in it's init, but adding it to the view controller's view within, say the `viewDidLoad:` method of the view controller.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your answer - However, I don't completely understand...

From what you've said, I moved the four lines of code that create the UIImage View into the `viewDidLoad` method and included a line in the Meteorite's init that changes the values of the `imageView` CGRect to the values that are passed through when an instance of the `Meteorite` class is created. However, since `imageView` is defined inside the `viewDidLoad` method, I cannot refer to it in the init of my Meteorite class.

Did I do what you suggested? Or, if not, where did I trip up? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Casper, can you give me a rundown of what you're attempting to accomplish, and what the meteorite object is for? (Sorry for late reply, was out for lunch.)

Comment: Hi Jacob, sorry, went off to bed - Essentially, I'm trying to spawn a meteorite every second on the screen with a random x value, so it appears as if there is a meteor shower. That is why I've defined a meteor class with variable properties.

Comment: What is the context of the app? Have you considered using SpriteKit for this as it would make it a bit easier and allow you better control over physics and movement.